# Android architecture : daemon or API, JNI or not

Tags: java, android, architecture, java-native-interface

A brief description of what I need to do :
I modify the android framework and create applications that both need to communicate with a program in C which runs in user space. This C program is basically a stub I wrote to interface with drivers and a bunch of APIs. It's practically empty in terms of complexity as it only used as a single entry point for hidden mechanisms, but it's a few thousand lines long.

Me and my internship tutor have diverging opinions about how this should be done :

1/ The application and the modified framework (clients) communicate with the C program using sockets, and the C program is turned into a daemon (server). The framework doesn't use any JNI -rather java sockets- and the applications might need to keep using a JNI implementation of sockets (didn't try java sockets yet for a .apk). This has been tested to work.

2/ Both the framework and the applications make calls to the C program, used somewhat like a library. This means -IMO- that we either "exec" from java (bad) or implement the whole code (2000+ lines, for now) inside the JNI.

My -biased- opinion on this :
1/

```
+ it's proven to work
+ there is a clear separation between low-level and high-level
+ there might be no JNI usage
+ because I use a C daemon, I can simulate the behaviour on x86 (using an environment provided by the manufacturer)
- architecture is somewhat complex
- depending on whether the .apk can use a java socket or not, the framework and the .apk won't use the exact same mechanisms to
interface with the daemon (java socket and JNI C socket)
```

2/

```
+ architecture would be simple (with the whole C in the JNI)
- maintaining is going to be a pain
- it's not simulable, development has to either be on target or on emulator
- the android FW has to use JNI (couldn't make this work so far because of a libc error)
- useless use of JNI (from what I understand, should be used for heavy calculations/low-level interfacing)
```

What's the correct Android way of doing this ? Does one method seem more elegant than its counterpart ?

Comment: Given the numbers of +-'s in your opinion, i assume that your tutor sides with 2. Can you present why? I side with 1 too because i have gone through a project already done as 2/ and reverting to 1/ (though not sockets but named pipes, so some JNI was left there after all). Don't get me wrong, i like JNI, but it's good to know its limits of convenience.

Comment: He doesn't exactly side with 2/ but he does want all the information before making a choice. That's good, but I can't squeeze more of it than I already did, so I need some help there :D. Thanks for your feedback.